# ¿Cómo crear una capa oscura al resto de la página al abrir el menú responsive?

Tags: jquery, css3

Como puedo añadirle este mismo efecto de este [menú responsive](http://synerise.com/). El efecto que aplica, al abrir el menú responsive es una capa transparente al resto de la página.

Trate de aplicar el estilo a la `class="slideout-menu"` pero el estilo me lo aplica al menú, lo ideal es aplicarle la capa transparente al resto del cuerpo de la página como se observa en este [menú responsive](http://synerise.com/).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.slideout-menu-toggle').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  // create menu variables
  var slideoutMenu = $('.slideout-menu');
  var slideoutMenuWidth = $('.slideout-menu').width();
  
  // toggle open class
  slideoutMenu.toggleClass("open");
  
  // slide menu
  if (slideoutMenu.hasClass("open")) {
    slideoutMenu.animate({
      right: "0px"
    }); 
  } else {
    slideoutMenu.animate({
      right: -slideoutMenuWidth
    }, 250);  
  }
});
});
```

```css
a {
  color: #777;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
  color: #515151;
}

.slideout-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right:-250px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
  z-index: 100;
}
.slideout-menu h3 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.slideout-menu .slideout-menu-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 9px 5px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  background: #222;
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.slideout-menu .slideout-menu-toggle:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.slideout-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  border-top: 1px solid #151515;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #454545;
}
.slideout-menu ul li {
  border-top: 1px solid #454545;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #151515;
}
.slideout-menu ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.slideout-menu ul li a:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.slideout-menu ul li a i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 10px;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="slideout-menu-toggle">Menu</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="slideout-menu">
  <h3>Menu <a href="#" class="slideout-menu-toggle">&times;</a></h3>
  <ul>
    <li>MENU AND MENU<li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="cuerpo">
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agrega un `<div>` como hijo directo del body con la cualquier clase. Éste será la capa que será tapará todo el body, excepto el menú ya que tiene un `z-index` muy superior.

Éste elemento debe tener las propiedades `visibility: hidden` y `opacity: 0` para que no sea visible y no tenga interacción con el usuario. Además, un `transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);` para que sea animable la visibilidad de la capa.

```
.capa {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  height: 100vw;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10; /* para que cubra otros elementos que tengan un z-index mayor a 1 */
}
.capa.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Otro aspecto interesante es que animas vía jQuery cuando en la clase `open` de `slideout-menu` puede hacerse ésto:

```
.slideout-menu.open {
  right: 0;
}
```

**Ejemplo**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.slideout-menu-toggle').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  // create menu variables
  var slideoutMenu = $('.slideout-menu');
  var slideoutMenuWidth = $('.slideout-menu').width();
  
  $('.capa').toggleClass('visible');
  
  // toggle open class
  slideoutMenu.toggleClass("open");
  
  // slide menu
  /*if (slideoutMenu.hasClass("open")) {
    slideoutMenu.animate({
      right: "0px"
    });
  } else {
    slideoutMenu.animate({
      right: -slideoutMenuWidth
    }, 250);  
  }*/
});
});
```

```css
a {
  color: #777;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
  color: #515151;
}

.slideout-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right:-250px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
  z-index: 100;
}
.slideout-menu h3 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.slideout-menu .slideout-menu-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 9px 5px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  background: #222;
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.slideout-menu .slideout-menu-toggle:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.slideout-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  border-top: 1px solid #151515;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #454545;
}
.slideout-menu ul li {
  border-top: 1px solid #454545;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #151515;
}
.slideout-menu ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.slideout-menu ul li a:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.slideout-menu ul li a i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 10px;
  opacity: .5;
}
.capa {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  height: 100vw;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10; /* para que cubra otros elementos que tengan un z-index mayor a 1 */
}
.capa.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.slideout-menu.open {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="slideout-menu-toggle">Menu</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="slideout-menu">
  <h3>Menu <a href="#" class="slideout-menu-toggle">&times;</a></h3>
  <ul>
    <li>MENU AND MENU<li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="cuerpo">
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
</div>

<!-- capa-->
<div class="capa">
  
</div>
```

**PD:** el timming de la animación lo hice mediante `cubic-beizer` porque te permite realizar funciones de tiempo de manera personalizada; de ésta manera puedes hacer transiciones más suaves. Puedes ver información de ésta propiedad [aquí](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-cubic-bezier/).

Comment: Perfecto funciona muy bien, más que todo el efecto de transiciones más suaves, solo por curiosidad si al realizar clic fuera del menú responsive o fuera del cuerpo del menú responsive cómo ocultar el menú al hacer clic o otras funciones fuera del menú responsive, gracias saludos :)

Comment: Como al abrir el menú se muestra la capa, lo que debemos hacer es añadir un listener a la capa para evento click, con el fin que cuando se haga click en ella se esconda el menu. `$('.capa').on('click', function () { $('.slideout-menu').removeClass('open'); })`

Comment: Gracias por el ejemplo, lo he probado me oculta el menú pero queda activo la capa puedes chequerarlo [https://jsfiddle.net/](https://jsfiddle.net/ux9qqsek/) Saludos :)

Comment: Te faltó quitar la clase `visible` a la capa: Mira [tu fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/guzgarcia/ux9qqsek/3/) corregido.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que podrías hacer es añadir un nuevo `div` que tenga `z-index` menor que el menú (pero mayor que el cuerpo) con posición fija que ocupe toda la pantalla, con fondo semitransparente y oculto. Entonces cuando se abra el menú (que se le añade la clase `.open`), ese `div` se vuelve visible.

Ni siquiera haría falta añadir nada de código JS, bastaría con añadir el `div` justo detrás del menú:

```
<div class="slideout-menu">
  <h3>Menu <a href="#" class="slideout-menu-toggle">&times;</a></h3>
  <ul>
    <li>MENU AND MENU<li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="scrim"></div>
```

Y el siguiente CSS:

```
#scrim {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:99;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
  display:none;
  transition:all 1s;
}

.slideout-menu.open ~ #scrim {
  display:block;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.slideout-menu-toggle').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  // create menu variables
  var slideoutMenu = $('.slideout-menu');
  var slideoutMenuWidth = $('.slideout-menu').width();
  
  // toggle open class
  slideoutMenu.toggleClass("open");
  
  // slide menu
  if (slideoutMenu.hasClass("open")) {
    slideoutMenu.animate({
      right: "0px"
    }); 
  } else {
    slideoutMenu.animate({
      right: -slideoutMenuWidth
    }, 250);  
  }
});
});
```

```css
a {
  color: #777;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
  color: #515151;
}
#scrim {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:99;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
  display:none;
  transition:all 1s;
}
.slideout-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right:-250px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
  z-index: 100;
}
.slideout-menu.open ~ #scrim {
  display:block;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.slideout-menu h3 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.slideout-menu .slideout-menu-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 9px 5px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  background: #222;
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.slideout-menu .slideout-menu-toggle:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.slideout-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  border-top: 1px solid #151515;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #454545;
}
.slideout-menu ul li {
  border-top: 1px solid #454545;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #151515;
}
.slideout-menu ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.slideout-menu ul li a:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.slideout-menu ul li a i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 10px;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="slideout-menu-toggle">Menu</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="slideout-menu">
  <h3>Menu <a href="#" class="slideout-menu-toggle">&times;</a></h3>
  <ul>
    <li>MENU AND MENU<li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="scrim"></div>
<div id="cuerpo">
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Te voy a dejar un ejemplo muy parecido al que estas utilizando, sería otra opción muy práctico y funcional para nuestra personalización `CSS`

He modificado un poco el sistema 'jQuery', para así poder trabajar mejor con nuestros elementos `CSS`, sin necesidad de añadir cajas extras para personalizar elementos al hacer clic, así logramos mejor optimización en nuestro código.

La clase (.open) al hacer clic, la añadimos a nuestro cuerpo (body), para así poder modificar fácilmente nuestros elementos `CSS`, ya que es el gran padre de sus elementos, si uno desea implementar desplazamiento en el cuerpo (body), sería posible fácilmente mediante simple `CSS`.

Ejemplo jQuery:

```
$('body').toggleClass('open');
```

Algo importante, es un scroll para el menú en vertical, para muestra correctamente todos los elementos `<li>`, siempre sería posible mediante `librerías jQuery` personalizar dicho scroll.

Los efectos de animación, la añadimos mediante `CSS`, un ejemplo:

```
transition: right .5s linear; //Seria un efecto para nuestro desplazamiento en la caja menú padre.
```

**Veamos el código modificado:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  //Boton
  $('.slideout-menu-toggle').click(function() {

    $('body').toggleClass('open');

  });
    
});   

//Cerrar menu
function closeNav() {
   $('body').toggleClass('open');
}
```

```css
body { 
  overflow-x:hidden; 
  transition: background-color .5s linear; /*Animacion CSS3 para fondo transparante en nuestro cuerpo al cerrar.*/
} 

a {
  color: #777;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
  color: #515151;
}

ul { list-style-type: none; }

#cuerpo {
  transition: all .5s linear ; /*Animación CSS, cuerpo giratorio cerrar*/
}

.slideout-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right:-250px; /*Invisible menu*/
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  /*Regla visible scroll en vertical*/
  overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:hidden;
  transition: right .5s linear; /*Animacion CSS3, para desplazamiento menu al cerrar.*/
  z-index: 1000; /* Z-index alto */
  
}
.slideout-menu h3 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.slideout-menu .slideout-menu-toggle, .cerrar-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 9px 5px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  background: #222;
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}    

.slideout-menu-toggle { z-index:999; }

.slideout-menu .slideout-menu-toggle:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.slideout-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  border-top: 1px solid #151515;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #454545;
}
.slideout-menu ul li {
  border-top: 1px solid #454545;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #151515;
}
.slideout-menu ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.slideout-menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.slideout-menu ul li a i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 10px;
  opacity: .5;
}
/*** Trabajamos con nuestra 'CLASS' 'OPEN', podriamos crear grandes personalizaciones, ya que podemos llegar a nuestros elementos hijos desde el 'BODY (open)' ***/

/*Añadimos fondo al cuerpo*/
.open {
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  transition: all .5s linear; /*Animación para fondo transparante en nuestro cuerpo al abrir.*/
}

/* Visible menu */
.open .slideout-menu { 
  right:0;
  transition: right .5s linear; /*Animacion CSS3, para desplazamiento menu abrir.*/
}
/* Cerrar menu desde cualquier lugar de pantalla */
.open .slideout-menu-toggle { 
   color:rgba(255,255,255,.0);/* Invisible texto */
   display:block; 
   position:fixed; 
   height:100%; 
   width:100%; 
   left:0; top:0;       
 }

/* Ejemplo, para ver lo facil que seria cambiar estilos, en este caso tu caja #cuerpo le vamos añadir un pequeño efecto. */
.open #cuerpo {
  transform: rotate(-3deg) ;
  transition: all .5s linear ; /*Animación CSS, cuerpo giratorio abrir*/
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="slideout-menu-toggle">Menu</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="slideout-menu">
  <h3>Menu <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="cerrar-menu" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a></h3>
  <ul>
    <li>MENU AND MENU<li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
    <li>MENU AND MENU</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="cuerpo">
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
  <p>Qolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibham liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima.</p>
</div>
```